# Msvcr90.dll file error

Tags: dll, runtime-error, msvcr90.dll

I have build a mfc application. I built it as "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)". and I run it. It worked fine. But due to some reasons i have to change it to "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)". I dit it. and when i run it it give an error

The program can't start because MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

After that I copied files "msvcr90.dll" and "Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest" to the debug folder.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT

And now when I run it it gives me runtime error. r6034. An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

What should i do now. HOw to run my application.

Comment: Your machine is broken, you'll need to fix it.  Then reinstall VS.